# centre iframe absolute position in html page

Tags: html, iframe, positioning, absolute, clipping

I have an iframe which I have clipped at the top, but want to centre on the webpage and zoom on load. I can clip it, but cannot position it, even with a relative div container, so as to maintain the clipped area at the top.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weat/drud5xwr/3/)

```
<div id="content">
<div id="myiframe">
  <iframe src="http://www.flippity.net/fc.asp?k=15r4rRJ- 
   hrZW2kAjUhpv1ZcqsWaUFci7O9e2ItxBDfO0"  height=700px  width=800px  
 scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:0;
}
#content #myiframe {
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
    width:800px;
}
```

Comment: This code centres the iframe nicely but it is still makes the iframe flush against the top of the container. Adding margins etc, makes the whole frame larger, moving it down to reveal the top bit.